# sftp: command not found

Tags: shell, sftp

I need to access SFTP and manipulate files in a certain directory via shell script but I'm getting this error 'sftp: command not found'. I'm using Cygwin.

Is there any way/command to make this work?

Comment: I'm not up on Cygwin, but a quick look at their web site suggests that SFTP isn't part of a 'standard' install, but can be installed as an extra. You can install or update Cygwin by running their Setup utility. Details are [here](http://cygwin.com/install.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sftp` command is typically part of the `openssh-client` package.

For Cygwin, run the `setup.exe` command (or `setup-x86.exe`, or `setup-x86_64.exe`) and install the "openssh" package, which you'll find under the "Net" category. If you're running cygwin, you should already have the installer; if not, you can download it from cygwin.com. (The older `setup.exe` was replaced a while ago by separate `setup-x86.exe` and `setup-x86_64.exe`; the latter doesn't yet support all packages.)

(For Linux systems, `openssh` is typically divided into `openssh-client` and `openssh-server` packages.)

This assumes that the `sftp` you're looking for is the "secure file transfer program".